# Full text of Act of Settlement, 1781 - during the early company rule in India

Tags: legal-history, indian-constitutional-law

Can someone please tell me where I can find the full text of the Act of Settlement, 1781 passed by the British Raj in India?

I tried finding it on the internet but couldn't find it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will find it on page 210 of [this volume of the *Statutes at Large* in Google books](https://books.google.ch/books?id=r4RaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA210):

> An Act to explain and amend so much of an Act, made in the thirteenth Year of the Reign of his present Majesty, intituled, An Act for establishing certain Regulations for the better Management of the Affairs of the East India Company, as well in India as in Europe, as relates to the Administration of Justice in Bengal; and for the Relief of certain Persons imprisoned at Calcutta in Bengal, under a Judgement of the Supreme Court of Judicature; and also for indemnifying the Governor General and Council of Bengal, and all Officers who have acted under their Orders or Authority, in the undue Resistance made to the Process of the Supreme Court